# Convert json object to array to store data in mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js

```
convert [{
"name":"abc"
},
{"name" : "xyz"
}]

to

(abc),(xyz)
```

Convert object of array to array to store mulitple records into mysql

Comment: Now would be a good time to read through [ask]? You should be showing us what you attempted to solve this problem yourself and any research you have done. There are many many questions on this site alone about transforming arrays

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `map` function like this:

```
map(function (v) {
  return v.name;
});
```

**Snippet**

```js
var a = [{
  "name": "abc"
}, {
  "name": "xyz"
}];
a = a.map(function (v) {
  return v.name;
});
console.log(a);
```